# Split large text file according to record values

Tags: windows, powershell, python

There are some questions alike in this site, but mine is a bit different.

I have a **30 GB text file**, and I need to split it into smaller  files according to the different record values.

For example;

```
   NAME       DATE      AMOUNT  
    AA      02.03.2014  768,30
    AA      03.03.2014  234,15
    BB      12.01.2014  238,00
    BB      15.09.2014  567,00
    BB      06.12.2014  323,00
    CC      08.02.2015  456,00
    CC      09.02.2015  213,00
```

into ---->

**AA.TXT**

```
   NAME       DATE      AMOUNT  
    AA      02.03.2014  768,30
    AA      03.03.2014  234,15
```

**BB.TXT**

```
   NAME      DATE        AMOUNT 
    BB       12.01.2014  238,00
    BB       15.09.2014  567,00
    BB       06.12.2014  323,00
```

**CC.TXT**

```
   NAME     DATE         AMOUNT
   CC      08.02.2015    456,00
   CC      09.02.2015    213,00
```

[Here I've found a clue](https://superuser.com/a/466385/105993), but I barely know Powershell scripting, so I couldn't figure out a way to split files according to the NAME value.

In the answer which I've cited above, it seeks for a bracket `[` , what I seek is a different value from the one above in the NAME column.

AND;

Smaller files in .txt formats will do the job BUT the following is appreciated:

--*If row count is < 1.000.000 , then extract the records into a .xls (or .xlsx) file.*

Any solutions in any other languages are also welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Did the python solution work?

Answer (score 2):

Python:

```
cpath="C:/Path/to/File"
infile=cpath+"/data.txt"

with open(infile) as f:
for line in f:
         content = line.split()

         outfile = cpath + "/" + content[0] + ".txt"

         with open(outfile,'a') as f2: 
              f2.write(line)
```